# What is view controller when a view is added to UIWindow in an iOS app?

Tags: ios

When I add a view to UIWindow by addSubView, What is ViewController for the subview that set to rootViewController of UIWindow?

What I am confused is that I don't create a ViewController for the subview explicitly and set its view property to my own view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the view does not belong to a view controller.